# Redirect loop on non-admin login

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm getting a redirect loop on a Drupal 7 install. Whenever a non-admin user logs in, the site will enter a redirect loop on the user profile URL; for example, http://example.com/?q=user/testuser.

This URL is accessible with no issues by the superuser account, and attempting to access this URL while logged out returns a 403 Access Denied as expected.

When logged in as a non-admin user, attempting to access any URL at all will redirect to the user profile page, which will then redirect onto itself, causing the redirect loop to start anew.

I have found that if I give a specific user the "administrator" role, the redirect loop will cease for that user, and the page will no longer try to redirect to user/%username on login.

I have also found that if I give users the "administer users" permission that the redirect loop will cease, but will still redirect the user to user/%username on login.

Obviously neither of these solutions are possible as giving regular users administrator roles or the ability to administer users is a huge security risk.

Does anyone know of a fix for this, or a way to get around this with an override related to user role?

Installed modules: Block, Color, Comment, Contextual links, Dashboard, Database logging, Field, Field SQL storage, Field UI, File, Filter, Help, Image, List, Menu, Node, Number, Options, Overlay, Path, RDF, Search, Shortcut, System, Taxonomy, Text, Toolbar, Update manager, User, Chaos tools (7.x-1.0-alpha4), Page manager, Devel, Theme Developer, Fieldgroup, IMCE, Pathauto, Token, Taxonomy Menu, IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge, Wysiwyg, Webform, and several custom modules which i) provide blocks 2) provide custom pages and 3) modify the default search behaviour (splits search results by node type). None of my custom modules ever interface with the user management system, permissions system or use any of the functions provided by the user module.

Comment: Update: I am also using a custom theme. If I switch to the "Stark 7.2" theme that ships with Drupal 7, the problem disappears. Does this mean my problem exists in my custom theme layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an identical problem... spurred on by the fact I wasn't the only one faced with this issue I dug around a bit more. It was your update that gave it away - the Custom Theme.

I'm sure this could be caused by lots of different factors, but in my case and potentially yours, it was my template.php that was at fault.

I was using a custom `MYTHEME_preprocess_page()` to make some custom variables available in my templates. One of the variables was obviously a bit funky because when i removed it the problem disappeared. Turns out it was some left over code from when I was trying to get the user registration form into the page. It never worked and I forgot to remove it!

Hope this helps someone out there get back on track.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't solution, but you can investigate in next way:
1. Goto http://SITE/admin/config/development/devel for devel module settings.
2. Check "Display redirection page" and save settings.
3. Goto http://SITE/admin/people/permissions
4. Check "Access developer information" for anon and other roles, and save.
5. Try login, it should stop on redirection pages and show where it try to redirect, so you can detect, what modules call looping.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with redirect-loops randomly occurring for non-admin users. Looking at `/admin/reports/dblog` revealed a permission problem with several nodes. I fixed it by flushing the node permissions (see `/admin/reports/status/rebuild`). Now everything is fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me, after hours and hours of debug and forum/blog navigation I finally found what was going on my site...

If you force login block in all pages, even if user is already logged in, only admin can navigate pages.

This is one of the possibles causes, I hope can help someone!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because i was loading the login form even when the user was logged in. fix it by not asking for the form only if the user is anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

from https://www.drupal.org/node/1793230

Run these SQL queries in your MySQL database. If you have drush installed, you can just "drush sqlc" from your settings directory to get into a MySQL command line. Otherwise you can use PHPMyAdmin, MySQL workbench, or some other client tool to connect and run these:

Show records to be deleted:

```
SELECT r.rid, r.language, r.source, r.redirect  FROM redirect r INNER JOIN url_alias u ON r.source = u.alias AND r.redirect = u.source AND r.language = u.language;
```

Then, to delete redirects shown in above query - try going to the pages shown in the row. Chances are you will get a redirect loop. Then, try again after backing up db and running the delete below. You have to turn off safe mode in MYSQL Workbench to run it, so BACKUP:

```
DELETE r FROM redirect r INNER JOIN url_alias u ON r.source = u.alias AND r.redirect = u.source AND r.language = u.language;
```

Fixed my problem, and found other pages that had loops which I didn't even realize!